# Stockwell transform in Python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I'm curious if there is a way to perform the Stockwell transform in Python with the use of the Scipy package (numpy, matplotlib, etc.) with addition of nice and clean visualization in the time/frequency domain as I shown below:

[image]

Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: I thought there was not a single specific S transform, but it was a family of transforms?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [MNE](http://www.martinos.org/mne/stable/auto_examples/time_frequency/plot_stockwell.html#example-time-frequency-plot-stockwell-py) for getting power content in time-frequency domain. [here](http://www.martinos.org/mne/stable/auto_examples/time_frequency/plot_stockwell.html?highlight=stockwell) is an example how it works. It is written for analysis of EEG/MEG signals but it should work fine for other purposes as well.