# The syntax for computing the Stockwell transform using the MNE package?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I'm trying to compute the Stockwell transform of an EEG signal, and can't seem to find a command for doing so using anything in scipy. In a post from 2015 ([Stockwell transform in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620007/stockwell-transform-in-python/31503331)), @Jariani suggested using the MNE EEG analysis package with which I am familiar. However, the command usage documentation  at https://mne.tools/0.11/auto_examples/time_frequency/plot_stockwell.html requires constructing "events" and "epochs" first.

All I want is the transform for one channel without defining these quantities first if possible. Here's my code thus far:

```
import mne as mn
from mne.time_frequency import tfr_stockwell
# Read in raw EEG file and pick off data and times:
raw=mn.io.read_raw_edf('/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/myfile.edf', preload=True)
data,times=raw[:,:]

# Constuct the data matrix of dimension numnber_of_times -by- number_of_channels:
X=data.T

# Try to compute Stockwell transform for first channel, where frequencies from 6 to 30 Hz:

power = tfr_stockwell(X[:,0], fmin=6., fmax=30., width=.3, return_itc=False)
```

The error message states among other things "TypeError: inst must be Epochs or Evoked," which leads me to believe I can't input a simple times series for one channel.

Any help using the syntax correctly or suggesting some other means for computing the Stockwell Transform would be appreciated. I've tried the package at https://github.com/claudiodsf/stockwell but can't seem to follow the installation process.